# Custom CTRL+Z handling? (Avoid crash)

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I created my first Blender operator: If the user selects 1 or more objects, and presses a button, a Python script will replace all the selected objects with cubes of the same size & location. The function first iterates through the objects and saves their data in an array and then deletes them, then it uses that array to create corresponding cubes. Anyway, if I press `CTRL`+`Z` it usually crashes Blender, since it can't always undo everything.

Is there a way to control what happens when I (or any user) presses `CTRL`+`Z` immediately after triggering the custom operator? (In my case, I would want to save all the objects I deleted, and then re-add them). Or even prevent Blender from trying to **undo** that action?

Comment: You may looking for `bpy.app.handlers.undo_post`. Blender may crash when you access a invalid pointer. For example: `cube = bpy.context.object`>`undo`>`print(cube.name)`